# Downscaling Sensor output

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

I'm looking to do some measurements with a 
[Sharp GP2Y0A21YK0F](https://www.pololu.com/product/136) IR Analog Distance Sensor.

Vcc 4.5-5.5 V

The Analog Output is: max Vcc+0.3V

Unfortunately, my DAQ can only handle 0-3V analog-in.

So my idea is to just scale the voltage down from the sensor by using resistors in a voltage divider.

I could use a second opinion on this

Thanks!

Comment: Abs max output voltage is Vcc+0.3V. Looking at the graphs on the datasheet output during normal operation is just above 3V. You *might* be ok if you just put a series resistor + clamp diodes (will possibly lose the 6~10cm range).

Answer (score 5):

The analogue output of the [sensor](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J85/gp2y0a21yk0f.pdf) is this: -

[image]

In other words it only creeps a little above 3V so use a light potential divider to drop the maximum down to a few tens of mV below 3V. Unfortunately the [data sheet](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J85/gp2y0a21yk0f.pdf) gives no indication of its output impedance so this will be a bit of trial and error but I suspect 180 ohms and 3k3 down to ground is a good starting point - this would reduce a peak 3.1 volts to 2.94 volts.

> The Analog Output is: max Vcc+0.3V

No, that's the maximum range of voltages you can put on the pin.

Comment: "No, that's the maximum range of voltages you can put on the pin." 
- On what pin? To my understanding the analog output, is that of V_o, i.e. the sensor pin output. 
e.g. Having a supply voltage of 5V would results in a max 5V+0.3V = 5.3V output on the V_o pin.

Comment: You are mistaking absolute maximum values for working or operational values. The graph shows the working values and be sensible; how is an output going to produce a voltage level 0.3 volts higher than the supply. Absolute max values are how far you can push the chip before damaging it.

Comment: I agree, but let's say that my supply voltage starts drifting towards 6 or 7 V. 
Wont the V_o (sensor output pin) go as high as 5.3V BEFORE it stops working? 
Which would damage my DAQ input pin before damaging the optical sensor?

Comment: The recommended operating conditions for the sensor is 4.5 volts to 5.5 volts. If you are not using a regulated supply you should be because, at the very least, your signal will drift with supply voltage variations and you lose accuracy fundamentally. There will also be a maximum current that your DAQ input pin can safely take so you can rely on the resistor network for limiting this current and, if necessary scale resistors up to 1.8 kohm and 33 kohm. If input Imax is 10mA, the 1k8 would have to develop 18 volts across it before damage would occur.

Answer (score 1):

A resistor divider is a good solution here.

[image]

The gain of this circuit is R2/(R1 + R2).  After a little algebra, you find that R2 is 1.5 times R1.  For example, R1 could be 10 kΩ and R2 15 kΩ.  In practice you probably want to make R2 just a little less to tolerate a little over-voltage.

So far we have two degrees of freedom but only one constraint.  The single constraint causes the divider to convert 5 V to 3 V.  The remaining freedom is the impedance.  This sets how much the input of the divider loads the signal, and how stiff the output is driving the A/D.  The input impedance is R1+R2, and the output impedance is R1//R2.  In the above example, the input impedance is 25 kΩ and the output impedance 6 kΩ.

Look at what your device can drive and what impedance the A/D requires.  Hopefully they are not off by more than 4.2:1 ratio this divider delivers.  If the A/D needs more than the 4.2 times less impedance than the device can drive, then you have to add some active buffering.  With some A/Ds, the input impedance spec is at maximum rate, and can be relaxed by extending the acquisition time before starting each conversion.